# How to remove a fence post in concrete that is attached to the garage foundation?

Tags: foundation, fence, post, cement

Even though I told a handyman to put the fence post that is right next to the garage in gravel, he put it in concrete. It is so close to the garage that it is scraping the siding and the concrete is now attached to the foundation. How can I fix this please?

Comment: Reciprocating saw and angle grinder to cut it off and bring it level with the ground. Or try to break up that piece of concrete.

Comment: Why not have the handyman back and redo it to your specifications as originally requested?  Since he didn't follow instructions, it should be his cost to redo the work.

Comment: Have you looked into firing squads?

Comment: What is scraping the siding, the post or the concrete?

Answer (score 2):

Pouring some new concrete next to the foundation for the fence post shouldn't really *attach* it to the foundation very firmly - but even if it's not attached it would be a lot of work to dig up the concrete the fence post is set in.

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the fence post is too close to the siding and might scrape and damage the siding. It might be easier to shave some of the fence post off, making it more narrow and creating more clearance. It wouldn't be the easiest cut to make but might be easier than re-setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a couple pieces of blocking that snugly fill the gap between the post and the garage, and then fasten the post to the garage through these blocks. Some people would add a third block down low and cut a section out of the post to free it from its foundation.